# css stylesheet not linking to index.html

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am learning to work with html and css through making an about me page. I've created a folder called blog and in there I have a file called index.html and a folder called css. In the css folder I have a file called style.css.

For some reason I can't find the error in my code that won't allow me to link my stylesheet to my index file. I am testing out the code on safari by simply opening the file.

here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stephanie CD</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hey! I'm Stephanie</h1>
    <p>how are you doing?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my style.css file:

```
h1  {
    color: blue;
}
body    {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Gm84ZeZ.jpg?1");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I simply restarted everything, made new files, and now it works. Don't know what went wrong.

thanks

Comment: you could try `<link href=“./css/style.css” rel=“stylesheet”>`

Comment: Maybe removing the non-standard double-quotes will do the trick. Those look like they come from Microsoft Word or something.

Comment: I just tried both of the suggestions, but nothing has changed when I open it in safari.

Comment: You are using wrong quotes, instead of `“ ”` use `" "` - `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: what text editor are you using that has theNetwork tab in developer tools?

Answer (score 2):

I tested my suggestion in Chrome and found that the resource in the funky quotes was not being requested.

The test is to try to load with and without the funky quotes and see which file actually attempts to load, create a HTML document with just this:

```
<link href=“css/style-1.css” rel=“stylesheet”>
<link href="css/style-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and then watch the Network tab in your developer tools to see which file is actually requested by the browser.

This still may not be your specific issue but it worked for me (i.e. style-2.css attempted to load but style-1.css did not).

Comment: The lesson here being to use a proper code editor and not something with WYSIWYG formatting (or worse). http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: @isherwood Indeed, Microsoft Word is inferior to Notepad when it comes to writing code... And if anyone is looking for a good IDE, check-out Eclipse, it's free and I like it more than Dreamweaver.

Comment: [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) is free and is the best!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm not sure where the funky quotes came from. I fixed the quotes, but it still doesn't work when I open it up in Chrome. What text editor are you using that has theNetwork tab? I am using Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing the CSS file correctly. Is the `css` folder in the `blog` folder? I did a fiddle and your styles loaded fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Ch8EQ/

Comment: @stecd In Chrome, press F12. This will open your developer tools (which are invaluable). Then click on Network (one of the options across the top of the dev. tools). To see the newtwork waterfall, you need to have the developer tools open before loading the page, if you open them after loading the page, reload it. At this point the Network tab will show you every network connection made because of your website, including ones that failed (they will be red). This way you can see if any network connection was even made for your CSS file, or if it was, it might help you figure out why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

my case was different.

```css
p{
   background: red;
   color: white;
   }
  
h1{  
  background: lightblue;
   color: green; 
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link href="css files\style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     <!--**IMPORTANT** while on pc I had to mention the full relative 
     path to get the desired output.
     link href="C:\Users\Arun\Documents\css files\style.css" 
     type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" THIS WORKED.-->
</head>
<body>
 <p>this is a simple paragraph.</p>
 <p>this is a simple paragraph.</p>
 <p>this is a simple paragraph.</p>
 <p>this is a simple paragraph.</p>
 <p>this is a simple paragraph.</p>

 <h1>hello, hi</h1>





</body>
</html>
```